# Can you break down this jquery code for me?

Tags: jquery, json

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) {
    $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
    });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/170/)
I saw this code and I'm not sure how it works. Especially `function(i,item)`. I read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) that the function after the comma is "A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request" but I'm not sure how the function grabs images from reddit automatically. I just want to learn how to use json with jquery as I've never touched it before.

Comment: It's grabbing the source of every image in the JSON. This question also doesn't belong here.

Comment: Open the [Javascript console](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/v07xk1ry/) and watch what happens when the script runs: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/v07xk1ry/

Comment: so where does this belong? I'm just curious how the ecode works and I can't figure it out myself. Stack overflow is for asking short questions, yes? I figured this was short enough to warrant posting here but you guys have a serious issue with being overly pedantic. Not every question on here needs to be something nobody has seen before. Of course I know what it's doing, I can read the fiddle output. I just don't know how it's doing what it does. The first response tells me what the fiddle output shows me already and the second one tells me to look at the fiddle output. Awesome.

Comment: Read the [FAQ on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You're not demonstrating a programming problem, hence this is a low-quality question on SO. It's pretty clear. And yes, your comment that every question here does not need to be a *different* question is wrong [to a degree](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). It is *not* the intention of SO to *teach you how to program*, it is to answer questions *related to a programming problem*.

Comment: I was *just* about to ask [whether SO is getting a "bad reputation"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446/are-we-being-elitist-is-there-something-wrong-with-that/262447) when I did a simple search and found a *very similar question* (imagine that!). Jon Skeet's observation that new users have a visceral reaction to downvotes is something I believe to be highly accurate (don't *ever*, ***ever*** post on meta if that hurts your feelings). The *mechanisms* of the rep/voting system are brusque and literal, but meant to be objective. I know I try to base it on the question, not the user.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json?jsonp=?", function(data) {
    // function body
});
```

Is an AJAX request to the given URL.  It expects that URL to respond with some JSON-formatted data.  When that response is received, the supplied function will execute with that expected data:

```
function(data) {
    // function body
}
```

This:

```
$.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
});
```

Will iterate over the values in `data.data.children` and execute the supplied function on each value:

```
function(i,item){
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).appendTo("#images");
}
```

The function supplied to the `getJSON` call and the function supplied to the `each` call are unrelated to one another.  The "outer" functions have no knowledge of what the "inner" ones are doing.

When put together as in the example you provide, all that's happening is an AJAX request is being made to the given URL and the data which is returned from that URL contains a collection of items.  That collection is iterated and used to create `img` elements on the page.

Comment: The `// unrelated` is confusing; why not just use an ellipsis, e.g., `...`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I wanted to explicitly point out that what *happens* inside the function call isn't relevant to the structure of the function itself in its relation to being passed to `getJSON`.